# How to order the way in which categories are shown in plotly.graph_objects.Scatterpolar plot

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, plotly-python

I am doing a Dash Project for a company, and I am stuck in plotting a Multiple Trace [Radar Chart](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/) in plotly. 
My current progress looks like this:-
[image]

**What I want is to find a way to get Data Science and Profile Building theta category close to each other**, so that the February-2020 trace is not a line but a **fill**, similar to how it shows in March-2020 trace. Till now I couldn't find any solution to it.

The data I used to plot the chart is as follows:-

[image: My Data]

Code for the chart:-

```
fig = go.Figure()
months = np.unique(df['month'].values).tolist()
months.reverse()
for i in months:
    temp = df.query('month=="{}"'.format(str(i)))
    q = temp['module'].values.tolist()
    r = temp['rating'].values.tolist()
    q.append(q[0])
    r.append(r[0])
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(theta=q,r=r,fill='toself',name=str(i),hoveron='points'))
fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
    radialaxis=dict(
      visible=True,
      range=[0, 10]
    )),
  showlegend=True
)
fig.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in Advance

Comment: June sort your dafaframe in the order you want.

Comment: @Ghanem I tried doing so already, but the graph looks weird in that case.